# how to make apple script filepath generic to handle any location

Tags: python, applescript

I am new to applescript and am stuck with a issue
I have a below apple script that works fine for saving into volume with a filename

```
         tell application "TextEdit"
            activate
            make new document with properties {text:" Apple Script example"}
            delay 5
            save document 1 in file ("DiskName:" & "anyfile.txt")
            close document 1
          end tell
```

I need to make the location agnostic so that i could be used for any location
This script works for Volumes but i need this to work for Destkop or Document location as well. Is there a simple way i could achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you would choose the destination when you run the script? Then try `set destFile to choose file name` and it will create a file specifier based on the location and name you choose and assign it to `destFile`.

Comment: @Mockman thank you but how do i handle both Volume and Default folder location in this case, set destFile to choose Filename i have seen it work for default folder but not any mounted folder

Comment: Ultimately, you will need to able to specify the path and filename somehow, and then feed that to the 'save' command. Is there something unusual about the mounted volume? Putting aside saving a file for a moment… If you have a file in a folder on this mounted volume, can you specify it and do anything with it in applescript?